# How can i correctly configure maven multimodule project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure my multimodule maven project like this :

Parent Project

- web
- dao
- core

```html
<modules>
    <module>../dao</module>
    <module>../core</module>
    <module>../web</module>
</modules>
```

My "web" module have one dependency to my "core" project and my core project to my "dao" project.

For example, my web pom contain :

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
</dependency>
```

When I build my parent project all build work fine but there is a very strange dependency copy. In fact, my parent project contains all child dependencies

[image]

For example, joda-time is in my web pom.

When I try to uncompress my web.war, it contains my core-jar-with-depency.jar and all the dependency.

```html
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I configure my parent project to disable dependency inclusion?

Comment: obviously this is how it will work .

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason for using classifier jar-with-dependencies? Looking at your need, I think you can do this ---

```
dao --> module with packaging jar
core --> module with packaging jar & dependency of dao without any classifier.
web --> module with packagingc war & dependency of core without any classifier.
```

Eventually your web war file will 'transitively' get core & dao & all its dependencies. See if this helps.

--- Update:

I just created one sample project with core module & web module in my GIT hub.

https://github.com/Ravikharatmal/MyGitRepo/tree/master/MultiModuleMavenProject

Web is dependent on Core. Core has a dependency on third party library commons-lang. When I do 'mvn install', you can see that the final web.war file has core.jar as well as commons-lang.jar i.e. transitive dependency of core.jar.

https://github.com/Ravikharatmal/MyGitRepo/tree/master/MultiModuleMavenProject/web/target/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have created "jar-with-dependency" to package all module with its dependency in specific file and include them in web like black-box.
Actually i have web.war witch contain all dependency project.

Comment: As far as I know, even without jar-with-dependency, a project with war packaging will package all the transitive dependencies inside war file i.e. if you do modules as above, then also your web.war will have core.jar, dao,jar & all other dependencies which are needed for dao.jar and core.jar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am surprised to see that the jar are downloaded by the parent in addition with the jar with dependency. It seems to be a normal operation.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this helped, please accept answer.